# Mocha: error with done() and callback

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I am stuck on a part of my test code with mocha, where the test is included in the callback of getUserMedia:

```
it("should work without error", function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia({fake:true}, function(stream) {
        expect(3).to.equal(3);
        done(); // done is not defined if expect() is valid
    },console.error);
});
```

Here, done() is not defined, but the test is successful.

```
it("should NOT work", function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia({fake:true},function(stream) {
        expect(3).to.equal(4);
        done();
    },console.error);
});
```

Here, I am getting an error:

```
AssertionError: expected 3 to equal 4
```

, but the mocha interface still shows the test as validated. (green tick)

Am i doing something wrong, or is done() is bugged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function should get a done argument.

```
it("should get done", function(done) {
  expect(3).to.equal(3);
  expect(3).not.to.equal(4);
});
```

However you should use done only if you have async function at the test
if not the test should be like this:

```
it("should not be async", function() {
  expect(3).to.equal(3);
}
```